# Angular 16 formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular 16 project and getting the `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance` error. I created the instance and to my knowledge am calling everything as needed. I hoping someone can spot what I'm doing wrong because I've been looking into this the last few days. If there is any other code/file that I might have missed please let me know.

**html**

```
<div class="widget-filters__list" [formGroup]="form">
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters; trackBy: trackBySlug" class="widget-filters__item">
    <div class="filter filter--opened" appCollapseItem="filter--opened" #collapseItem="appCollapseItem">
        <button type="button" class="filter__title" (click)="collapseItem.toggle()">
            {{ filter.name }}
            <span class="filter__arrow"><app-icon icon="arrow-rounded-down-12x7"></app-icon></span>
        </button>
        <div class="filter__body" appCollapseContent>
            <div class="filter__container">
                
                <app-filter-category *ngIf="filter.type === 'category'" [options]="filter"></app-filter-category>

                <app-filter-vehicle *ngIf="filter.type === 'vehicle'" [options]="filter" [formControlName]="filter.slug"></app-filter-vehicle>

                <app-filter-range *ngIf="filter.type === 'range'" [options]="filter" [formControlName]="filter.slug"></app-filter-range>

                <app-filter-check *ngIf="filter.type === 'check'" [options]="filter" [formControlName]="filter.slug"></app-filter-check>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component**

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject, map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { Filter } from 'src/app/interfaces/filter';
import { PageShopService } from '../../../auction/services/page-shop.service';
import { FilterHandler } from '../../filters/filter.handler';
import { filterHandlers } from '../../filters/filter-handlers';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-widget-filters',
 templateUrl: './widget-filters.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./widget-filters.component.scss']
})
export class WidgetFiltersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

filters: Filter[] = [];

form!: FormGroup;

constructor(
private page: PageShopService,
private fb: FormBuilder
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.page.list$.pipe(
  map(x => x.filters),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subscribe(filters => {
    console.log('Test')
  this.filters = filters;

  const filtersWithHandlers = this.page.filters
    .map(filter => ({ filter, handler: filterHandlers.find(x => x.type === filter.type) }))
    .filter((x): x is { filter: Filter; handler: FilterHandler; } => !!x.handler);

  const fields: { [filterSlug: string]: FormControl; } = {};

  filtersWithHandlers.forEach(({ filter, handler }) => {
    fields[filter.slug] = this.fb.control(filter.value);
    fields[filter.slug].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.page.setFilterValue(filter.slug, handler.serialize(value)!);
    });
  });

  this.form = this.fb.group(fields);
});
}
```

Comment: You never assign a `FormGroup` to `form`. You declare `form` as being a `FormGroup`, but you never give it a `ForGroup` to hold, and you used `!` to ignore the error that would be raised telling you what's wrong.

Comment: 1.- use `<div *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">`, the "if" avoid initial errors. 2.- use the method [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol) to add a new FormControl to a formGroup (or use `this.form=new FormGroup(fields)`). Remember that ther're two ways to declare a FromGroup, using `new` and use formBuilder.

Comment: I don't know about your "app-filter-...." components. Really I don't know if you use viewProviders or they are a custom form control or...

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a value to your formgroup during declaration like so (where you have it there, above your constructor):

```
form = this.fb.group({});
```

Then in the `ngOnInit`, or somewhere else in your code, you can add controls to that formgroup by doing something like this:

```
this.form.setControl('login', this.fb.group({ email: '', password: ''}));
```

The issue is that you need an initial value for your form. You could alternatively use an `ngIf` in your template file, like suggested in your comments, to handle the case where there is no initial value. But IMO it's easier to just give the formgroup an initial value.